# XMLHttpRequest cannot load using keycloak and docker

Tags: angular, docker, keycloak

I am running keycloak in docker container. Keycloak integrated with angular project.

The problem is after login inot keycloak redirect my angular project show the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/tenant-11/protocol/openid-connect/token. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:4201' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
zone.js:664 Error: Uncaught (in promise): undefined
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:766)
    at zone.js:844
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1427)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1445)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you have your answer in the error : "A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:4201' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute." Don't use "*" or try setting `withCredentials`to false

Comment: Thank you so much :) @Sébastien Blanc. It's working correctly